# How to shortcut a context menu on current file

Tags: windows-10

So current file is the file that I clicked on and I'd like to press for i.e: `F11` to open that file with a specific context menu (for i.e: `Edit with Notepadd++`)

Note: the `Shortcut key` in program's properties didn't help because it just invoke the program itself, not against the current file. (maybe I'm worng?)

System: gvim 8.1 / windows10

Answer (score 1):

I have following mapping in my vimrc wich opens an explorer window with the current file selected.

```
nnoremap <F11> :!start explorer /select,%:p<cr>
```

As follow up, you can press <kbd>Shift+F10</kbd> to open explorers context menu.

#### Complete context

```
  if has('win32')
    " MS-Windows
    if $USERPROFILE != ''
      let localvimrc = $USERPROFILE . '\_vimrc.local'
    endif

    " Open Windows explorer with current buffer selected
    nnoremap <F11> :!start explorer /select,%:p<cr>
  endif
```

Comment: Thanks for another view. Actually I'm assuming that we're having opening `explorer` and a file that was selected (single left click) and for i.e we press `F12` to open that file with `gvim`

Comment: Ah, I got it the other way around. For that, I would advise using AutoHotkey.

Comment: I'm using AutoHotkey for alwaysOnTop, can you elaborate string to achieve #1 behavior?

Comment: Following opens a file I've selected in explorer with vim *(gvim is in my context menu and has v as accelerator key)* `F10::Send +{F10}v{enter}
`

Comment: Extractly what I need, I have `F12::Send +{F10}s{enter}` in an `.ahk` file and it works well. Many thanks.

Comment: @TuyenPham - note that you can build some safeguard arround this by checking that the active window is an explorer window. Either that or knowing not to press F12 with another window active... The keystrokes will get send and all bets are of as to what might happen.

Comment: I've just changed to `+Enter` instead and totally happy to quick open file and then start to edit it immediately. I have like `#NoEnv`, `SendMode Input`, `SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%` in my `.ahk` but have no idea how `safeguard` would be.